# how to add objects on a listview?

Tags: java, android, class, listview, object

here the class with object

```
DeliveryItem deliveryItem = new DeliveryItem();
deliveryItem.setItem("milk");
deliveryItem.setQty("2");
deliveryItem.setUnit("Ltr");
arrayList.add(deliveryItem);
```

and arraylist set on listView

```
ArrayAdapter <DeliveryItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <>(this,R.layout.simple_arraylist,arrayList);
delivery_items.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: you need to create customer adapter, look at this tutorial https://www.javatpoint.com/android-custom-listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to create array list

```
List<DeliveryItem> arrayList=new ArrayList<DeliveryItem>;
```

than add your object in this arrayList like

```
arrayList.add(deliveryItem);
```

after that call you code like

```
ArrayAdapter <DeliveryItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <>(this,R.layout.simple_arraylist,arrayList);
delivery_items.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new item:

```
DeliveryItem newItem = new DeliveryItem();
newItem.setItem("sugar");
newItem.setQty("1");
newItem.setUnit("Kg");
```

add it to the list:

```
arrayList.add(newItem);
```

and inform the adapter about the addition:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```